# Mesclar array apenas em valores vazio

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma função que recebe como parâmetro um array, por exemplo:

```
$args = array(
    "foo" => "value"
);
oneFunction( $args );

function oneFunction( $array ){
    $default = array(
        "foo" => "foo",
        "bar" => "bar"
    );
    //mescla valores
    $array = mesclaArrays($default, $array);

    //nesse exemplo, a saída deve ser
    //array(
    //  "foo" => "value",
    //  "bar" => "bar"
    //);
}
```

Existe um função nativa pra isso ou é necessário eu criar a minha própria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer ao contrário e inserir na `$default` o que vem de fora com um loop.

```
function oneFunction( $array ){
    $default = array(
        "foo" => "foo",
        "bar" => "bar"
    );
    //mescla valores
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) $default[$key] = $value;
    return $default
}
```

Dessa maneira adicionas novas `chave -> valor` e/ou modificas *chaves* já existentes com o novo *valor*.

Comment: Caraca, por que não pensei nisso antes. Era tão mais simples que eu tava me enrolando e criando uma função gigante. Adaptei pras minhas necessidades e deu certinho. Muito obrigado amigo